# Jest: get undefined on import some module

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I'm making some test to redux with *jest* but I got sucked because `Auth` module appears as `undefined`.

```
import { auth as Auth } from 'Services/firebase'

export const signIn = (email, password) => {
  console.log(Auth) // It get's undefined
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(signInInit())
    Auth.signIn(email, password, (user) => {
      dispatch(push('/'))
      return dispatch(signInSuccess(user))
    }, (error) => {
      return dispatch(signInError(error))
    })
  }
}
```

This is the jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/coverage",
    "verbose": true,
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/public"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/__mocks__/fileTransformer.js",
      "^Components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components",
      "^Data(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/data",
      "^Hocs(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/hocs",
      "^Scenes(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/scenes",
      "^Services(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/services",
      "^Styles(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/styles"
}
```

Really can't understand why this is happening, well any clue will be very welcome.

Comment: if you're using thunk you need to be returning a function. where is your `dispatch` coming from?

Comment: thanks for your reply, the dispatch comes from *redux-thunk* thats working pretty good the problem is on testing *Auth* appears as `undefined`

Comment: How does your export looks like?

Comment: I'm exporting *auth* like this `export const auth = new Auth(Firebase.auth())`

Comment: What are you using for the module aliases? If it's webpack, have you looked at [Using With Webpack - Configuring Jest to find our files](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files)?

Comment: I've updated my question to provide more information and yes I've looked that

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas I know it's been over a year, but were you able to fix this? I have a similar situation going on with nrwl.